# Backup Solution for a difficult situation on debian

Tags: linux, debian, backup

I´m looking for a way to make non corrupted backups.

I tried rsnapshot but there is one problem. I can´t run the hourly backups via. a cronjob and so I can´t ensure that the daily backup is finished before the next hourly starts and rsnapshot doesn´t put the hourly into a queue. So if the hourly starts during the daily is running it changes the source of the daily, which corrupts the backup.

I have to run the hourly backups via. a java application at different times and the daily weekly... via. a cronjob.

Is there a way to prevent that the hourly backup changes the source of the daily backup, while the daily backup is running ?

Or how else could I solve this ?

---

edit:

I just read the man again and found sync_first 1, but I´m not sure if this would solve the problem, what do you think ? This is hard to try out.

Answer (score 0):

`sync_first` will resolve your problem. In fact, it should be on by default because having it defaulted to off makes little sense.

Comment: mhh, I´m not sure. See: If the daily backup is running (rotation) and the hourly backup ends and starts the "rsync hourly", does this wait until the rotation of the daily backup is finished ? Or how long does a rotation of 20gig backups with thousends of small files take ?

Answer (score 0):

There are also different solutions than `sync_first` which all solve your schedule problem :

- [Déjà dup](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/DejaDup?action=show&redirect=DejaDup) allows you to backup to a remote or local destination (encrypted transfert) : it uses duplicity as the backend. It will not procced to a backup until the previous one is finish.
- [rsync](https://rsync.samba.org/) is a very powerful tool very flexible. If you cannot use cron, you could create a rsync script launched manually or every time the computer shutdown.
- [SpiderOak](https://spideroak.com/) allows you to backup and synchronize files (across computers). It is a cloud based solution but which use zero-knowledge technology and, so, respect your privacy.